# JS. Представить целое число как дробный остаток?

Tags: javascript, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Первое, что пришло на ум:

```
function f(int){
return parseFloat("0."+int);
}
```

Но этот способ довольно медленный.
Может есть способ сделать это на уровне битов?

Comment: А зачем это надо? И вас действительно устраивает что результат для 10, 100 и 100000 будет одинаковый?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю делить на ближайшее большее число, представимое в виде степени числа 10:

```
function decPoint(int) {
    return int / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(int))+1);
}
```

Небольшая проверка работоспособности:

```js
function f(int) {
    return parseFloat("0."+int);
}

function decPoint(int) {
    return int / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(int))+1);
}

let max = 10000000;
function testF() {
    let t0 = window.performance.now();
    for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) f(i);
    console.log("f performance: " + (window.performance.now() - t0) / max);
}
function testDecPoint() {
    let t1 = window.performance.now();
    for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) decPoint(i);
    console.log("decPoint performance: " + (window.performance.now() - t1) / max);
}

testF();
testDecPoint();

let testNums = [5, 55, 555, 123, 1, 10, 100];
for (let tn of testNums) console.log(tn + " => " + decPoint(tn));
```

Превосходство в производительности для меня составило около 40%:

```
f performance: 0.00024259000000059603
decPoint performance: 0.0001450699999988079
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но подозреваю, что есть более простой способ.